# Scrollbar in JFileChooser gives error

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

When I use JFileChooser, the first time I use its scrollbar, I get two or four copies of the following error message:

```
2016-01-08 18:37:17.706 java[14158:2289154] inOptions: {
    JavaCUIThumbStartKey = 0;
    "is.flipped" = 0;
    kCUIOrientationKey = kCUIOrientVertical;
    kCUIThumbProportionKey = "0.497863233089447";
    max = 0;
    pressedpart = 0;
    state = normal;
    value = 0;
    widget = scrollbar;
```

Here is sample code that has this behavior:

```
package tests;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingTest extends JFrame {

    public SwingTest() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Choose files");
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                chooseFile();
            }
        });
    }

    private void chooseFile() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingTest test = new SwingTest();
        test.pack();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

My Swing programs continue to run (mostly), but this bothers me. What is causing this, and how can I avoid it?

Mac OS X 10.11.2 El Capitan
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Comment: What L&F are you using? I'm on Win7 with JDK1.8.0_25 and I get no error messages with Metal L&F.

Comment: Using the same OS/JRE, I can't reproduce this; but I've seen similar messages intermittently on 10.11.2. Since it's also seen with other graphics libraries, I'm guessing it's a platform debugging information enabled by the vendor.

Comment: *"I get two or four copies of the following error message:"*  At no point does the message mention 'error'..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! The problem only occurs with the default L&F, which on the Mac is apparently getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName(). The problem does not occur with explicitly setting the L&F to Metal or to Motif.

Although the word "error" does not occur, Eclipse presents the message in red, indicating that it is sent to syserr rather than to sysout.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Closed (Not reproductible) Java bug:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152662

It was closed because no test case was provided, not because it is not a bug.