# Scrolling a Swing JScrollbar in Java 8 in Mac OS X El Capitan produces error on console

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, osx-elcapitan

Dragging the knob in a vertical JScrollbar under Java 8 on Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.3 produces the following output on the java console:
(it is not marked as an error, but the font color is red, so it was send to the error log)
The error can not be reproduced on Mac OS Yosemite.

I also have the impression that the program hangs for some milliseconds.

My collegue said it might have to do with the implementation of the Mac OS look and feel. Anybody has any suggestion how this could be solved?

The output is:

```
2016-01-26 10:38:34.302 java[6066:842060] inOptions: {
    JavaCUIThumbStartKey = "0.3350805640220642";
    "is.flipped" = 0;
    kCUIOrientationKey = kCUIOrientVertical;
    kCUIThumbProportionKey = "0.06532712280750275";
    max = 0;
    pressedpart = 0;
    state = normal;
    value = "0.3585003614425659";
    widget = scrollbar;
}
2016-01-26 10:38:34.302 java[6066:842060] outHitPart = 0
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34688056/230513). I see it more often with long documents. Since it's also seen with other graphics libraries running atop Quartz, I'm guessing it's debugging information enabled by the vendor.

Comment: Have you installed Xcode 7.2?

Comment: As David Matuszek has said as a comment on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/34688056/4121347,  _The problem only occurs with the default L&F. The problem does not occur with explicitly setting the L&F to Metal or to Motif_.

Comment: @trashgod: yes i have installed XCode 7.2 on my system, but im developing with Netbeans 8.1

Comment: @trainrobbery: It seems to start after installing Xcode 7.2, but removing it doesn't help.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi: `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel` also works.

Comment: @trashgod That's good, because Nimbus is my favorite L&F !